# Replace substrings in python with the length of each substring

Tags: python, regex, string

How to replace a sub-string, say words that start with capital letters, with the length of that sub-string, perhaps using regex.

For example:
Using the regex `"\b[A-Z]+[a-z]*\b"`

> "He got to go to New York"

Should be transformed into this:

> "2 got to go to 3 4"

The actual scenario that I am using this in is a bit different, but I thought that scenario is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) for this which accepts a callable. That callable is called with match object each time a non-overlapping occurrence of pattern is found.

```
>>> s = "He got to go to New York"
>>> re.sub(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]*)\b', lambda m: str(len(m.group(1))), s)
'2 got to go to 3 4'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as succinct, but in case you want to avoid regular expressions and lambda's you can write something like this:

```
string = "He got to go to New York"
string = string.split()

for word in range(len(string)):
    if string[word][0].isupper():
        string[word] = str(len(string[word]))

print(" ".join(string))
```

Comment: This would fail with numbers/punctuation symbols.. E.g: `He got to New York, the most .. city.`