# Can motelling be vectorized in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

"Motelling" is a way to smooth response to a signal.

For example: Given a time-varying signal S<sub>t</sub> that takes integer values 1-5, and a response function F<sub>t</sub>({S<sub>0...t</sub>}) that assigns [-1, 0, +1] to each signal, a standard motelling response function would return:

- -1 if S<sub>t</sub> = 1, *or* if (S<sub>t</sub> = 2) & (F<sub>t-1</sub> = -1)
- +1 if S<sub>t</sub> = 5, *or* if (S<sub>t</sub> = 4) & (F<sub>t-1</sub> = +1)
- 0 otherwise

If I have a DataFrame by time of the signal {S}, is there a vectorized way to apply this motelling function?

E.g., if DataFrame `df['S'].values = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1]`
then is there a vectorized approach that would produce:

`df['F'].values = [-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1]`

---

Or, absent a vectorized solution, is there something obviously faster than the following `DataFrame.itertuples()` approach I am using now?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_integers(1,5,100000), columns=['S'])
# First set response for time t    
df['F'] = np.where(df['S'] == 5, 1, np.where(df['S'] == 1, -1, 0)) 
# Now loop to apply motelling
previousF = 0
for row in df.itertuples():
    df.at[row.Index, 'F'] = np.where((row.S >= 4) & (previousF == 1), 1,
                              np.where((row.S <= 2) & (previousF == -1), -1, row.F))
    previousF = row.F
```

With a complex DataFrame the loop portion takes O(minute per million rows)!

Comment: Do you need it to be vectorized or just fast?  Whenever something like this comes up I prefer to just compile it (Cython or Numba). Usually ends up more efficient and understandable

Comment: is your series St a pandas Series?

Comment: @evamicur – I just amended the question with my current solution using `.itertuples`.  I'm mostly interested in speed, so anything that significantly improves that is attractive.  (And of course bonus points for clarity ;)

Comment: @Usernamenotfound: I edited the question to assert that it is in a DataFrame, but that means it can be accessed as a Series.

Comment: sorry didnt see this response. I have what I believe to be a better way using Numba (if you can afford to use it 10000% recommended), will be posting soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To aggregate the other answers, first I should note that apparently `DataFrame.itertuples()` does not iterate deterministically, or as expected, so the sample in the OP doesn't always produce the correct result on large samples.

Thanks to the other answers, I realized that a mechanical application of the motelling logic not only produces correct results, but does so surprisingly quickly when we use `DataFrame.fill` functions:

```
def dfmotel(df):
    # We'll copy results into column F as we build them
    df['F'] = np.nan
    # This algo is destructive, so we operate on a copy of the signal
    df['temp'] = df['S']
    # Fill forward the negative signal
    df.loc[df['temp'] == 2, 'temp'] = np.nan
    df['temp'].ffill(inplace=True)
    df.loc[df['temp'] == 1, 'F'] = -1
    # Fill forward the positive signal
    df.loc[df['temp'] == 4, 'temp'] = np.nan
    df['temp'].ffill(inplace=True)
    df.loc[df['temp'] == 5, 'F'] = 1
    # All other signals are zero
    df['F'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

For all timing tests we will operate on the same input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,5,1000000), columns=['S'])
```

For the DataFrame-based function above we get:

```
%timeit dfmotel(df.copy())
123 ms ± 2.07 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This is quite acceptable performance.

[tai was first to present this very clever solution using RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49160744/2662901) (which is what inspired my function above), but it can't match the speed of staying in number space:

```
import re
def tai(s):
    str_s = "".join(str(i) for i in s)
    s1 = re.sub("5[45]*", lambda m: "x"*len(m.group(0)),str_s)
    s2 = re.sub("1[12]*", lambda m: "y"*len(m.group(0)),s1)
    l = list(s2)
    l2 = [v if v in ["x", "y"] else 0 for v in l]
    l3 = [1 if v == 'x' else v for v in l2]
    l4 = [-1 if v == 'y' else v for v in l3]
    return l4

%timeit tai(df['S'].values)
899 ms ± 9.69 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

But nothing beats compiled code.  Thanks to [evamicur for this solution using the convenient numba in-line compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49185622/2662901):

```
import numba
def motel(S):
    F = np.zeros_like(S)
    for t in range(S.shape[0]):
        if (S[t] == 1) or (S[t] == 2 and F[t-1] == -1):
            F[t] = -1
        elif (S[t] == 5) or (S[t] == 4 and F[t-1] == 1):
            F[t] = 1
    return F

jit_motel = numba.jit(nopython=True)(motel)

%timeit jit_motel(df['S'].values)
9.06 ms ± 502 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try regex.

The patterns we are looking for are

- (1) 1 follows by 1 or 2.  (We select this rule because any 2 comes after 1 can be considered as 1 and keep influence the next row's result)
- (2) 5 follows by 4 or 5. (Similarly any 4 comes after 5 can be considered as 5)

(1) will results in consecutive `-1`s and (2) will results in consecutive `1`s. The rest that does not match will be 0.

Using these rules, the rest of work is to do replacement. We espeically use a method `lambda m: "x"*len(m.group(0))` that can turn the matched results into the length of such matches. (see reference)

```
import re
s = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1]
str_s = "".join(str(i) for i in s)
s1 = re.sub("5[45]*", lambda m: "x"*len(m.group(0)),str_s)
s2 = re.sub("1[12]*", lambda m: "y"*len(m.group(0)),s1)
l = list(s2)
l2 = [v if v in ["x", "y"] else 0 for v in l]
l3 = [1 if v == 'x' else v for v in l2]
l4 = [-1 if v == 'y' else v for v in l3]
[-1, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1]
```

Bigger dataset

```
def tai(s):
    str_s = "".join(str(i) for i in s)
    s1 = re.sub("5[45]*", lambda m: "x"*len(m.group(0)),str_s)
    s2 = re.sub("1[12]*", lambda m: "y"*len(m.group(0)),s1)
    l = list(s2)
    l2 = [v if v in ["x", "y"] else 0 for v in l]
    l3 = [1 if v == 'x' else v for v in l2]
    l4 = [-1 if v == 'y' else v for v in l3]
    return l4

s = np.random.randint(1,6,100000)

%timeit tai(s)
104 ms ± 6.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,6,100000), columns=['S'])
# First set response for time t    
df['F'] = np.where(df['S'] == 5, 1, np.where(df['S'] == 1, -1, 0)) 
# Now loop to apply motelling

%%timeit  # (OP's answer)
previousF = 0

for row in df.itertuples():
    df.at[row.Index, 'F'] = np.where((row.S >= 4) & (previousF == 1), 1,
                              np.where((row.S <= 2) & (previousF == -1), -1, row.F))
    previousF = row.F

1.11 s ± 27.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Reference

[Replace substrings in python with the length of each substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27367834/replace-substrings-in-python-with-the-length-of-each-substring)

Comment: Yes!  Very clever, and it really is an order of magnitude improvement in speed!  (We can I/O DataFrame to fit OP via `df['F'] = tai(df['S'].values)`.)

Answer (score 1):

You may notice that since the consecutive elements of F[t] depend on one another this doesn't vectorize well. I'm partial to using numba in this cases. Your function is simple, it works on a numpy array (series is just array under the hood) and it's not easy to vectorize -> numba is ideal for this.

Imports and function:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def motel(S):
    F = np.zeros_like(S)

    for t in range(S.shape[0]):
        if (S[t] == 1) or (S[t] == 2 and F[t-1] == -1):
            F[t] = -1
        elif (S[t] == 5) or (S[t] == 4 and F[t-1] == 1):
            F[t] = 1
        # no else required sinze it's already set to zero
    return F
```

Here we can just jit-compile the function

```
import numba
jit_motel = numba.jit(nopython=True)(motel)
```

And ensure that the normal and jit versions return expected values

```
S = pd.Series([1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 5, 3, 4, 1])
print("motel(S) = ", motel(S))
print("jit_motel(S)", jit_motel(S.values))
```

result:

```
motel(S) =  [-1 -1 -1 -1  0  1  0  0 -1]
jit_motel(S) [-1 -1 -1 -1  0  1  0  0 -1]
```

For timing, let's scale:

```
N = 10**4
S = pd.Series( np.random.randint(1, 5, N) )

%timeit jit_motel(S.values)
%timeit motel(S.values)
```

result:

```
82.7 µs ± 1.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
7.75 ms ± 77.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

For your million data points (didn't time normal function because I didn't wanna wait =) )

```
N = 10**6
S = pd.Series( np.random.randint(1, 5, N) )
%timeit motel(S.values)
```

result:

```
768 ms ± 7.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Boom! Less than a second for a million entries. This approach is simple, readable, and fast. Only downside is the Numba dependency, but it's included in anaconda and available in conda easily (maybe pip I'm not sure).

Comment: note that to call the numba function you must use series.values, since numba does not recognize the series currently.

Comment: Wow: I hadn't come across numba before.  This is awesome!